# How do you page through entries in a structure?

Tags: structure

I have a structure like below and need previous / next links on an entry such that they go back and forth between E, F, G and H. They shouldn't step into D or I.

I've been trying this, but I can't get it not to step into D or I.

```
{%  set prev = entry.getPrev({section: 'mySection'}) %}

    {% if not prev %}
        {% set prev = craft.entries.section('mySection').last() %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ prev.title }}

    {% set next = entry.getNext({section: 'mySection'}) %}

    {% if not next %}
        {{ craft.entries.section('mySection').order('lft desc').first().title }}
    {% endif %}

    {{ next.title }}
```

- A

  - B
  - C
  - D

    - E
    - F
    - G
    - H
- I

  - J
  - K
  - L

    - M
    - N
    - O
    - P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Craft provides many helpful methods to traverse structure sections and your use case is no exception.

Instead of using `.getPrev()` or `.getNext()`, try [`.getPrevSibling()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getPrevSibling) or [`.getNextSibling()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getNextSibling) (or their aliases `.prevSibling` and `.nextSibling`.)

You could create prev/next links with something like this:

```
{% set prev = entry.prevSibling %}
{% if prev %}
    <a href="{{ prev.url }}">{{ prev.title }}</a>
{% endif %}

{% set next = entry.nextSibling %}
{% if next %}
    <a href="{{ next.url }}">{{ next.title }}</a>
{% endif %}
```