# Paginate children in a structure

Tags: pagination

Or to say it in a different way, paginate siblings.

I found this question on stack: [How do you page through child entries in a structure?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/how-do-you-page-through-child-entries-in-a-structure) which seems to have a working answer. However trying this myself I get no results.

To be clear, I have a two level structure.

```
Level 1 (parent)
 - Level 2 (child)
 - Level 2 (child)
 - and so on..
```

How can I paginate the children?

Thank you for any input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to paginate:

## To show next / prev links

#1
[getPrevSibling](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getPrevSibling) [getNextSibling](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getNextSibling)

```
{% if entry.getPrevSibling %}
    <a href="{{entry.getPrevSibling.url}}">{{entry.getPrevSibling.title}}</a>
{% endif %}

{% if entry.getNextSibling %}
    <a href="{{entry.getNextSibling.url}}">{{entry.getNextSibling.title}}</a>
{% endif %}
```

#2 [getPrev](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getPrev) [getNext](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getNext)

```
{% set params = {section: entry.section.handle} %}
{% set prev = entry.getPrev(params) %}
{% set next = entry.getNext(params) %}

{% if prev %}
    <a href="{{prev.url}}">{{prev.title}}</a>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
    <a href="{{next.url}}">{{next.title}}</a>
{% endif %}
```

## To show list of children (single type page)

[{% paginate %}](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/paginate)

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('sectionHandle').limit(10) as pageEntries %}

{% for entry in pageEntries %}
    <article>
        <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>
        {{ entry.body }}
    </article>
{% endfor %}

{% if pageInfo.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.prevUrl }}">Previous Page</a>{% endif %}
{% if pageInfo.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.nextUrl }}">Next Page</a>{% endif %}
```